# Django custom user model doesn't show up under Authentication and Authorization in the admin page

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours and feel lost. I am new to django and have tried to create a custom user model. My struggle is that my user model won't show up under the Authentication and Authorization section of the admin page. [Admin page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Ajy.png)

Here is my code for the model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import  AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
```

Here is the code for my admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from orders.models import User
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

here is a snippet of my settings.py file where i added the AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL='orders.User'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'orders'
```

]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same Problem. I found solutions that you can add `class Meta: app_label = 'auth'` But then i get an ImproperlyConfigured error.

Comment: Hey! How did you fix this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: You need to add this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'applicationName.CustomUserClassName'` on your settings.py

Answer (score -1):

You should not name your custom user model *User*. It will create issues with the base *User* model that you are extending.

The important thing to note is if you are using AbstractUser, then you do not need to override the username, first_name and last_name field if you're not going to do anything special with them because they are already implemented.

Your refactored User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models

class MyUser(models.AbstractUser):
    # Fields that you are not obliged to implement
    # username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    groups = None
    user_permissions = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

User admin:

```
@admin.register(MyUser)
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username']
```

or,

```
admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

In settings.py you can take out the AUTH_USER_MODEL which is not necessary unless you are creating the User model from scratch.

Comment: Hi! I've changed my custom user model's name to `Profile" and the rest is just like you wrote but I am also having the same problem. Any more recommendations?

Comment: Are you sure you have registered your models correctly ?