# Get Django Custom user model listed under admin app `Authentication and Authorization`

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users

Note my question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160700/django-custom-user-model-doesnt-show-up-under-authentication-and-authorization), however that answer recommend not calling the customised user model `User`, whereas the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) and [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) do.

I created a custom User model in an app called `plug`:

`plug/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Requirements:
    - Must be defined in models.py, due to the way settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is defined
    """
    is_hamster = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superhero = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_pogo_stick = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        # app_label = 'auth'  # <-- This doesnt work
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

`settings.py` file set accordingly:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'plug.User'
```

`plug/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

@admin.register(get_user_model())
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_hamste', 'is_superhero', 'is_pogo_stick')
    list_display_links = list_display
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Leasing User Role', {'fields': ('is_hamste', 'is_superhero', 'is_pogo_stick')}),
)
```

All is good except in the admin interface the custom user is listed under the heading `Plug` instead of under `Authentication and Authorization` (where `Users` used to be listed, along with `Groups`).

I tried setting `app_label = 'auth'` in the meta of the custom user model, however then it fails with the error:

```
File "/home/michael/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in __new__
    new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
  File "/home/michael/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 228, in register_model
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'user' models in application 'auth': <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'> and <class 'dist.plug.models.User'>.
```

How does one get a custom user model to be listed under the default app admin heading of `Authentication and Authorization` ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the way is not adding your user model to the existing section, but rather remove groups from the existing section, and adding it to ones own section:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as DjangoGroup
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin as BaseGroupAdmin


class Group(DjangoGroup):
    """Instead of trying to get new user under existing `Aunthentication and Authorization`
    banner, create a proxy group model under our Accounts app label.
    Refer to: https://github.com/tmm/django-username-email/blob/master/cuser/admin.py
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('group')
        verbose_name_plural = _('groups')
        proxy = True


admin.site.unregister(DjangoGroup)


@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(BaseGroupAdmin):
    pass
```